# How can I edit the custom options text in the created invoice PDF in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options, invoice, pdf

OK, so we have this site that has a lot of custom options and we'd like to ideally have the label and value on the same line when the invoice PDF is created. I have located the file responsible at

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

and have made a copy at

app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

but my PHP is not good enough for me to figure out how to have the label and value on the same line.

This is the code in question:

```
$options = $this->getItemOptions();
if ($options) {
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        // draw options label
        $lines[][] = array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
            'font' => 'italic',
            'feed' => 35
        );

        if ($option['value']) {
            if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                $_printValue = $option['print_value'];
            } else {
                $_printValue = strip_tags($option['value']);
            }
            $values = explode(', ', $_printValue);
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $lines[][] = array(
                    'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 30, true, true),
                    'feed' => 40
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to keep the checks and just have the 'text' be in this form: 'label' - 'value'

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, copying files that can just be overridden from the Core to Local is not best practise as it can possibly give you more work when upgrading Magento.

I have tested your case and found your solution:

First of all I rewrite it in my own extension:

```
 <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite><order_pdf_items_invoice_default>MycompanyName_Myextensionname_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default</order_pdf_items_invoice_default></rewrite>
            </sales>
 </models>
```

Then I override the function you mentioned above:

```
 $options = $this->getItemOptions();
    if ($options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option['value']) {
                if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                    $_printValue = $option['print_value'];
                } else {
                    $_printValue = strip_tags($option['value']);
                }
                $values = explode(', ', $_printValue);
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    $lines[][] = array(
                        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label'] . " - " . $value), 40, true, true),
                        'feed' => 40
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I have done here is just removed the part where you draw the label and added it to the part where you print the value.

If you have long labels/values and you want to keep it on one line, I would increase the value in str_split.